# What version of Microsoft Edge am I using?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, browser-support

When I look at the Settings pane in Microsoft Edge, it shows me two figures like so:

[image]

I don't know which of these denotes the version.

[This page](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-version/edge) suggests that the latest version of Edge as of today is version 44.something.

That leads me to think I am using version 42 (from the screenshot of my Edge installation I pasted above) and not version 17. That and the fact that no matter how many times I run Windows update, it does not update my installation of Edge. These two facts lead me to believe that I am only 2 versions behind the latest version, and so I am not missing out on any latest Web development support.

However, when I read the `navigator.userAgent` property, it reads (line breaks added for readability):

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 
Edge/17.17134"
```

suggesting that I am using version 17.

This coupled with the fact that [my installation of Edge fails to load ES 6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55546730/303685) confuses me.

That, and the fact that there's no direct way to update to a new version of Edge. You must rely on Windows update to do it for you if it feels like doing it.

And that there are two numbers in my settings and neither of them indicate precisely which of them denotes the version number.

All these things are making it very difficult for me to like this browser.

1. What's my version of Edge?
2. How do I get the latest one if I am not already using the latest one?

Comment: You're using Edge version 42, which internally uses [EdgeHTML engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdgeHTML) version 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge 42.17134.1.0 - This denotes the version of the Web Browser

EdgeHTML 17.17134 - This denotes the version of the Web Renderer.

These are two different components of the Edge Web Browser

**The only way to update Edge as far as i can see is to update windows 10.**

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies it somewhat. I understand the difference. Now just one question remains. How do I get the latest version?

Comment: Edge is bundled within Windows 10, i would make sure you are on the latest version of Windows 10 v1809

Comment: Thank you. Looks like the problem of Edge not running my modules might be elsewhere and that I may already have the proper version of Edge. 8 more minutes before I mark your answer as the right one.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 you dont have the latest version. My version of Edge is https://i.imgur.com/T1xIumH.png

Comment: Thank you. I will re-run Windows update tonight. I have run it several times but it does not update Edge.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 you may need to use https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3159635/windows-10-update-assistant